# Put a button at the end of a recyclerview with swiperefreshlayout

Tags: android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

i want to to put a button at the end of a scrollview, i know that i can achieve this if i modify my adapter but i don't want to do it in that way because i think there's an easier way. So i tried modifying my layout like this:

```
<!-- Not important stuff -->

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refreshIndicatorCoins"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvCoinsFull"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

This works almost perfect but swipeRefresh's animation freezes

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps.

After RecyclerView put this code.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It didn't wok :(

Comment: Post something. which tell what exactly you want

Comment: i dont want the swiperefresh's animation to stop